# How do I use SQL Server table name in select query with a variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Is this incorrect, can't we pass the table name to a select query dynamically?

This is giving me a error 'Must declare the table variable @TblName'

```
DECLARE @TblName VARCHAR(30)
SET @TblName = 'User'
SELECT * 
FROM @TblName
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to create a dynamic SQL query, preferably using the [**QUOTENAME**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function. You can avoid any issues from malicious input by using *QUOTENAME* function.

Here is a sample script that illustrates how to query a table by creating a dynamic SQL query by passing in a table name. You can change the table name by value to the variable `@tablename`.

#### Create and insert script for sample:

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
    id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO sample (id) VALUES
  (1),
  (2),
  (3),
  (4),
  (5),
  (6);
```

#### Dynamic SQL script:

```
DECLARE @execquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tablename AS NVARCHAR(128)

SET @tablename = 'sample'
SET @execquery = N'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @execquery
```

#### Demo:

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05097/8)

#### Suggested read:

[**The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL**](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `dynamic` sql execution

wrap your statement in `@selectstr`

use `exec sp_executesql @selectstr`

Comment: the parameter for sp_executesql needs to be nvarchar/nchar/ntext

Comment: -1 - It's really a bad idea to just give someone code for dynamic SQL without explaining it at all.  `Here's a gun, try not to shoot yourself.`

Comment: very indeed answer @Sive provided , I would have learn that for next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing by using dynamic query, Check below

```
DECLARE @TblName VARCHAR(30)

DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(100)

SET @TblName = 'User'

SET @vQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TblName

EXECUTE sp_executesql @vQuery
```