# How to use a variable in SQL statement From Line

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a procedure that allows for a variable to be used as a table name.

Example:

```
Select Temp1, Temp2 
From @var
```

The @var has the correct table name but changes with each iteration through the while loop.

```
-- Above sets up all Variables
WHILE @Count >= @I
BEGIN 
SET @ObjectID = (SELECT ObjectID FROM @TmpTable WHERE ID = @I)
SET @TableName = (SELECT TableName FROM @TmpTable WHERE ID = @I)
IF @I = 8
BEGIN

        SELECT * 
        INTO ##TMPTable
        FROM @TableName
        -- Additional Processing
END
END
```

Comment: you can't without using dynamic SQL (Building a string with the select and then executing that string) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678725/how-to-set-table-name-in-dynamic-sql-query or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325044/dynamic-sql-passing-table-name-as-parameter or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521144/how-do-i-use-sql-server-table-name-in-select-query-with-a-variable... take your pick all say dynamic SQL

Comment: I don't get it. How is it changing? It's not being used in the loop. More code? :-p

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding dynamic sql if you can find another way: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Comment: Do you even need a loop here? What is the "additional processing"? This sort of screams of poor design but there isn't much information to go on. Of course they way you have this coded the loop seems really pointless since you are only going to anything when @I = 8.

Comment: @I= 8 is only for testing so that I can work with one table. The main goal is to copy data  to a temp table so that we can recreate a schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE   
   @SQLString varchar(max),  
   @TempTableName varchar(100)  

SET @TempTableName = '##TMPTable' + cast( @@spid AS varchar(5))  

WHILE @Count >= @I
BEGIN 
SET @ObjectID = (SELECT ObjectID FROM @TmpTable WHERE ID = @I)
SET @TableName = (SELECT TableName FROM @TmpTable WHERE ID = @I)
IF @I = 8
BEGIN

        set @SQLString = '
        SELECT * 
        INTO ' + @TempTableName + '
        FROM ' + @TableName

        EXECUTE ( @SQLString )  

        EXECUTE ( 'SELECT * from ' + @TempTableName)  

        -- Additional Processing
END
END
```