# Having difficulty accessing variable from outer cursor in SQL Server (Transact)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

Below is my code, it doesn't do much at the moment but my ultimate goal is to look at every text-like field in the database, checking it for a certain condition and modifying it if necessary.

I've been building towards this and everything was going okay until I actually tried to retrieve the value in the column.

The problem occurs when I try to `set @CurrentValue`. The `top 1` code is just temporary until I later extend the code but this is not the problem. In testing this I discovered that it errors when trying to make use of `@TableName` from the inner `while` loop.

```
Must declare the table variable "@TableName".
```

I'm not an expert with procedural Transact SQL. Is there a way I can access this variable from this location?

```
--Edit following config lines as necessary
USE mytable
DECLARE @SchemaName SYSNAME = 'dbo'
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.name 
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
  WHERE s.name = @SchemaName
  and lower(t.name) like 'online%';

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor
INTO @TableName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        PRINT '-----'
        PRINT @TableName
        PRINT '-----'

        DECLARE MatchingColumns CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE 
        TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND
        DATA_TYPE in ('nvarchar', 'varchar', 'ntext', 'text', 'nchar', 'char');

        DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)

        OPEN MatchingColumns

        FETCH NEXT FROM MatchingColumns
        INTO @ColumnName

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN

            DECLARE @CurrentValue NVARCHAR(MAX)

            set @CurrentValue = (
                select top 1 @ColumnName
                from @TableName
            )


            PRINT @ColumnName

            FETCH NEXT FROM MatchingColumns
            INTO @ColumnName

        END

        CLOSE MatchingColumns
        DEALLOCATE MatchingColumns

        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor
        INTO @TableName


    END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable) - in fact, too late for me to flag, but I like this one better because it warns about quoting: [How do I use SQL Server table name in select query with a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521144/how-do-i-use-sql-server-table-name-in-select-query-with-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
set @CurrentValue = (
                select top 1 @ColumnName
                from @TableName
            )
```

ON

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(200)
set @cmd  = N'SELECT TOP 1  @CurrentValue=' +  @ColumnName + ' from ' + @TableName
EXECUTE @CurrentValue = sp_executesql @cmd, N'@CurrentValue VARCHAR(MAX)',  @CurrentValue OUT
```

Comment: An answer should also explain _why_ it's changing what it's changing.

Comment: I tried to do this and it simply returned a number. When I debug it I can see it has produced the correct SQL `SELECT top 1 MyColumn from MyTable varchar` and nothing crashes, but `CurrentValue` has a value of `214` instead of the text value.