# Dynamic table name in SQL cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

@Table_R nvarchar(50)

```
FETCH NEXT FROM M_cursor INTO @M_col    

PRINT 'Mandatory Feilds ' + @M_col 

Select count(*) from @Table_R where @M_col is null'    


FETCH NEXT FROM M_cursor INTO @M_col
```

I will send the table name as parameter ' @Table_R' , But in the cursor it throws an error.

1. How to use dynamic table in the Sql Cursor.

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql - tablename as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable)

Answer (score 2):

You should use dynamic sql command sp_executesql (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). See example:

```
DECLARE @A numeric
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'Select @a=count(*) from '+ @Table_R+ ' where ' + @M_col + ' is null',
      N'@A numeric OUTPUT', 
      @A OUTPUT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Select count(*) from @Table_R where @M_col is null
```

with

```
EXEC('Select count(*) from '+@Table_R+' where '+@M_col+' is null')
```