# Worklight SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I want to send a query to different tables. I want to take the table name as the parameter so I used "?" but it gives an error when I invoke it. If I write the table name instead of "?" without any parameters, there is no error. Can you guys suggest a solution? Thanks.

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * from ?");
function getStudentInfos(param1) {    

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement,
        parameters : [param1]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to take the table name as a parameter in a static sql query.
The only way to do this is to create the sql query dynamically.
Take a look here:
[Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable)