# MySql.Data error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: c#, mysql

The following code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO `@tableName` (@tableKeys) VALUES(@tableValues)";

MySqlCommand sql = new MySqlCommand(query);
sql.Connection = connection;
sql.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@tableName", values[0]));
sql.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@tableKeys", values[1]));
sql.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@tableValues", values[2]));
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Returns the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''porto,date') VALUES('232,17-11-2014 10:48:11')' at line 1

And I call on the code using this:

```
string[] values = {"logs","porto,date",num+","+date};
bool dbopen = dbManager.OpenConnection();
if(dbopen){
   dbManager.Insert(values);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have table name as parameter.

Comment: so how can i achieve what im trying to do here then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql - tablename as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/sql-tablename-as-variable)

Comment: `INSERT INTO 'log' (porto, date) VALUES (@num, @date)` and add 2 parameters for @num and @date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** parameterize your table names and column names.

You can only parameterize your values. You need to add your table name and column name as a part of your sql query.

You should either perform very stringent validation on the table name before putting it into the SQL, or have a whitelisted set of valid table names, in order to avoid SQL injection attacks in the normal way.

Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem myself using this piece of code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO `"+values[0]+"` VALUES("+values[2]+")";
        MySqlCommand sql = new MySqlCommand(query);
        sql.Connection = connection;
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```