# Need to create a new table from existing table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

I want to create a new table with existing table, where the table names should to pass from input parameters.
I am trying the following code.

```
DECLARE @oldTableName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @newStagingTableName nvarchar(50)
SET @oldTableName='OldTableName'
SET @newStagingTableName ='NewTableName';
SELECT * INTO @newStagingTableName FROM @oldTableName WHERE 1 = 0;
```

The SQL server is giving error while parsing this query.

Comment: `@newStagingTableNameFROM` is this a typo or have you not added a space?

Comment: Incorrect syntex near '@newStagingTableNameFROM', Expecting '.', ID, or QUATED _ID.

Comment: It was typo here only.

Comment: try  exec(@mySQLstr)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Comment: The way this is posted leads me to suspect your code is vulnerable to sql injection. All the answers posted so far are vulnerable. You need to wrap the object names with QUOTENAME. It is not perfect but is very simple and helps prevent sql injection quite easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try below dynamic SQL query?

```
DECLARE @oldTableName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @newStagingTableName nvarchar(50)

SET @oldTableName='OldTableName'
SET @newStagingTableName ='NewTableName'

DECLARE @sqlquery nvarchar(100) = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @newStagingTableName + ' FROM ' + @oldTableName
exec(@sqlquery)
```

Comment: Wrapping the two table variables with QUOTENAME would go a long way towards preventing sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

On the line

```
SELECT * INTO @newStagingTableNameFROM @oldTableName WHERE 1 = 0;
```

you do not have a space between @newStagingTableName   and FROM

also check does the table NewTableName exist ? and if so you cannot just access it directly via a parameter - you would need to use dynamic SQL - perhaps [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) can help

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
DECLARE @oldTableName NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @newStagingTableName NVARCHAR(50),
        @sql                 NVARCHAR(100)=''

SET @oldTableName=''
SET @newStagingTableName ='';
SET @sql='select * INTO ' + @newStagingTableName
         + ' FROM ' + @oldTableName + ' WHERE  1 = 0;'

EXEC sp_executesql
  @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work . . .

```
DECLARE @oldTableName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @newStagingTableName nvarchar(50)
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
SET @oldTableName='oldTableName'
SET @newStagingTableName ='newStagingTableName ';

SET @sql='SELECT * INTO ' +  @newStagingTableName + ' FROM ' + @oldTableName + ' WHERE 1 = 0;' 

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

**EDIT:** *Sorry I didnt see that other guys answered it*