# Set table based on stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

We have a process that updates certain tables based on a parameter passed in, specifically a certain state. I know organizationally this problem would be eliminated by using a single table for this data, but that is not an option -- this isn't my database.

To update these tables, we run a stored procedure. The only issue is that there was a stored procedure for each state, and this made code updates horrible. In order to minimize the amount of code needing to be maintained, we wanted to move towards a single stored procedure that takes in a state parameter, and updates the correct tables. We wanted this without 50 If statements, so the only way I could think to do this was to save the SQL code as text, and then execute the string. IE:

```
SET @SSQL = 'UPDATE TBL_' + @STATE +' SET BLAH = FOO' 
EXEC @SSQL;
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using strings to update the correct tables based on that parameter. These stored procedures are thousands of lines long.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Instead save entire script as SQL text and execute it, just update the required table using like code below as where you need and rest continue as it is

```
EXEC('UPDATE TBL_' + @STATE +' SET BLAH = FOO')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could, indeed, use dynamic SQL (the `exec` function) - but with long, complex stored procedures, that can indeed be horrible.

When faced with a similar problem many years ago, we created the stored procedures by running a sort of "mail-merge". We'd write the procedure to work against a single table, then replace the table names with variables and used a PHP script to output a stored procedure for each table by storing the table names in a CSV file. 
You could replicate that in any scripting language of your choice - it took about a day to get this to work. It had the added benefit of allowing us to easily store the stored proc templates in source code control.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use sp_executesql which is fairly more appropriate than a simple EXEC command. To do so, even with input and output parameters :

```
DECLARE @sql       nvarchar(4000),
        @tablename nvarchar(4000) = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME',
        @params    nvarchar(4000),
        @count     int

SELECT @sql =
    N' UPDATE ' + @tablename +
    N' SET Bar = @Foo;' +
    N' SELECT @count = @@rowcount'

SELECT @params = 
    N'@Foo int, ' +
    N'@count int OUTPUT'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, 2, @count OUTPUT
SELECT @count [Row(s) updated]
```

I encourage you reading the related part of the article mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2838507/2955677).