# sql select with tablename as variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have a couple of tables that can only be accessed using sybase. I need to write a query that will extract data from July to a date parameter specified (eg. 201507 - 201512). Once the date parameters has been inputted, I need to access tables on sybase with the names:
ff_vv_201507_tt to ff_vv_201512_tt.

I though of perhaps having the yyyymm as a variable. I am not sure how to implement this as I am pretty new to SQL.

I have tried accessing one table from sybase but my code did not seem to work:

```
DECLARE @Table_Name sysname, @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)

SET @Table_Name = 'ff_vv_201507_tt'

SET @DynamicSQL =  'select 
*
FROM OPENQUERY(SADATABASE, 'select 
*
                       from  ' @Table_Name ' 
                                         )''

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It would be helpful to know what Product and Version from Sybase you are using, as not all support Dynamic SQL.  If you are unsure, use `select @@version` to find that information.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) 
 Jun 28 2012 08:36:30 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Then why would you put Sybase in the title and tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Comment: I believe OP is executing on SQL Server, but additionally using OPENQUERY to pull some information from SyBase into SQL Server.

Comment: What error are you getting and have you tried the openquery without the dynamic sql using one of the tables you would query to make sure that it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a shell script with inline sql.
This way, you will easily generate and pass your parameters to a stored proc, and also create dynamically your tables with the given parameter
Example of such a script :

```
$PARAM="XXXXX"
$PARAM2="YYYYY"
ret=`$ISQL -U$SQL_USER -P$SQL_PASSWD << __XXX
set nocount on
go
use mydatabase
go

DECLARE @batchId INT
select @batchId = 99
exec myStoreProc @batchId, "${PARAM}", "${PARAM2}"
go
__XXX`
```

Comment: I don't see how this makes sense either

Answer (score 0):

If you want single quotes in your your strings you need to "escape" them by having two single quotes.

```
SET @DynamicSQL =  'select * FROM OPENQUERY(SADATABASE,''select * from '+@Table_Name+''')'
```

---

Why so complicated this should work fine.

```
SET @DynamicSQL =  'select * FROM ' +@Table_Name 

EXECUTE @DynamicSQL
```

Comment: I have tried this but since I am using OPENQUERY it does not seem to work.

Comment: @MissR - did you escape your single quotes as I show above?