# SQL Server - select into from statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
select column
from table_53;
```

Now, I want to get this 53 from another table, so what I want to do is something like this:

```
select column
from table_(select id from table2);
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: Why do you store the table-id in a table?

Comment: I sense poor DB design here. But `sp_executesql` can help you here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Comment: Thinking about this a bit more, I'm terrified of this design. And this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/17/sql-server-list-schema-name-and-table-name-for-database/ can also help with the cludging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need dynamic sql query here.**

```
declare @sqlQuery = 'select column
from table_(';

set @sqlQuery = @sqlQuery + 'select id from table2)';

EXEC (@sqlQuery)
```

Note :- One of cons of using dynamic sql query is sql injection. I would suggest to have better table structure or try to used parameterized query.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the way SQL thinks and works. Maybe your suggested approach can be mimicked by way of writing stored procedures in which you create SQL-statements which are then evaluated. However, this will not be very efficient.

A better approach would be to store the values of all your individual separate tables into one master table and mark them in a separate column `tblid` with their number (e.g. `53`). Then you can always filter them from this master table by looking for this `tblid`.

Comment: Totally agree on the "SQL thinks and works". Just imagine what mess this "design" can create?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but using something like this:

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @ID = ID FROM TABLE_2;
--IF @ID EQUALS 53 THEN
SET @QUERY = 'SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE_' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10));
-- @QUERY EQUALS TO 'SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE_53'
EXEC (@QUERY);
```