# Using variable inside dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL..What I am trying to do is use the Parameter defined at the stored procedure level inside dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] 
    (@DealID NVARCHAR(500),
     @OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT,    
     @FeeType CHAR(1)
    )  --  I want to use this parameter inside dynamic SQL query
AS    
    DECLARE @exec_str NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @exec_str = N'DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
                      SELECT * FROM @FeeType'    --This is where I want to use the variable

    DECLARE @ParamDefinition nvarchar(max)
    SET @ParamDefinition = N'@OUTPUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT'

    EXEC sp_executesql @exec_str, @ParamDefinition
```

Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot use a parameter for an identifier, such as a table name, alas.

Comment: Your table name is a single character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server Identifiers can't be parameterized.
Since you are using dynamic SQL anyway, you can do something like this:

```
SET @exec_str= N'Select * from '+ @FeeType 

EXEC(@exec_str)
```

However, this is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. To reduce the risk to minimum you should check first that such a table name exists, and I would also use [`quotename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) just to be on the safe side:

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Information_Schema.Tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @FeeType
)
BEGIN
    SET @exec_str= N'Select * from '+ QUOTENAME(@FeeType)
    EXEC(@exec_str)
END
```