# Pyodbc: How to select from a table that has string/variable name

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have been having some issues trying to create (or select) from tables where the name is dependant on the variable I am giving it.

E.g below is an example of a code I tried that didn't work, where 'Hey' = the name of the table (which exists in the database) that I am trying to select through the variable 'j'.

```
j = 'Hey'
rows = conn.execute("SELECT * from ?", (j,)).fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `?` is meant for bound parameters, and unfortunately, table names won't work in this manner. However, this will, but be careful of SQL injection:

```
j = 'Hey'
rows = conn.execute("SELECT * from {table_name}".format(table_name=j)).fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Unfortunately, you can't bind it to a T-SQL variable name either, as you're just passing the problem downstream to a T-SQL `EXEC` command, as outlined here: [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable) Please also note this is due to the design of SQL Server and T-SQL, not `pyodbc`.

Good luck!