# Displaying name of a table which is held in variable after executing a query with it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just wrote the following script. I'm wondering if it is possible to display the table name after each select statement so I can actually see from which table I have results.

```
Declare @tables table (table1 varchar(50));
declare @table varchar(50);
declare @tablename varchar(50);

INSERT INTO @tables select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
COLUMN_NAME ='order_id'

While (Select Count(*) From @tables Where table1 IS NOT NULL) > 0
BEGIN
set @table = (select top 1 table1 from @tables)

EXEC ('IF EXISTS (SELECT order_id from [' + @table + '] where order_id = 
13940001 ) 
SELECT * FROM [' + @table + '] where order_id = 13940001
'
) 


                    --!! Remember to put replace those order_ids with your 
order_ids on both these lines

delete from @tables where table1 = @table

END
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
Declare @tables table (table1 varchar(50));
declare @table varchar(50);
declare @tablename varchar(50);

INSERT INTO @tables select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where 
COLUMN_NAME ='order_id'

While (Select Count(*) From @tables Where table1 IS NOT NULL) > 0
BEGIN
set @table = (select top 1 table1 from @tables)

EXEC ('IF EXISTS (SELECT order_id from [' + @table + '] where order_id = 
13940001 ) 
SELECT * FROM [' + @table + '] where order_id = 13940001
SELECT @table'
) 


                    --!! Remember to put replace those order_ids with your 
order_ids on both these lines

delete from @tables where table1 = @table

END
```

But then I encounter this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@TABLE".

And I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Comment: @table doesn't exist outside of the session, you know that when you build your dynamic SQL above, so why not try how you have done it above SELECT @table?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the idea, your variable doesn't exist outside of the session, so you could include it in your select, so you know where each select comes from:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(255);
SELECT  @table = 'This is my table name'

PRINT ('IF EXISTS (SELECT order_id from [' + @table + '] where order_id = 
13940001 ) 
SELECT *,'+''''+@table+''''+' FROM [' + @table + '] where order_id = 13940001')
```

Produces:

> IF EXISTS (SELECT order_id from [This is my table name] where order_id
>   =  13940001 )  SELECT *,'This is my table name' FROM [This is my table name] where order_id = 13940001

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer in your question:

```
EXEC ('IF EXISTS (SELECT orderid from [' + @table + '] where orderid = 
13940001 ) 
begin
SELECT * FROM [' + @table + '] where orderid = 13940001
select ''' + @table + '''
end
')
```