# Sytnax issue in SQL query written in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, syntax

I have the fallowing code which aim is to extract some sensor data and insert in to a MySQL database.

```
def sendDataToDB(con, data, table):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s (`sensor_id`, `value`, `unit`, `datetime`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (table, data.uuid, data.value, data.unit, data.datetime))
    con.commit()

temperatureSens = TemperatureSensor(0, 'temperature', 'celsius')
con = connector.Connect(user = db_user_name, password = db_password, database = db_name, host = db_host, port = db_port)

temp = temperatureSens.extractData()
print(temp.uuid, temp.value, temp.unit, temp.datetime)
sendDataToDB(con, temp, 'temperature_data')
```

The data is extracted correctly(this is the purpose of the print statement) but i have an error in the syntax  of the INSERT query which i really cant find. There is the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
the right syntax to use near ''temperature_data' ('sensor_id', 'value', 'unit',
'datetime') VALUES (0, 23.0, '' at line 1
```

I'm sure that the problem is in the python syntax(which i'm nor very fimilar with) but i can't find it.
Thank you in advice.

EDIT** the root cause issue is that it is messed up (`) sign with (') in the INSERT query.

Comment: `INSERT INTO %s ` table name cannot be parametrized. You need to use string interpolation or concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

As **Lukasz Szozda** said table name can not be a parameter,see [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable),also you need add `'` to wrap `%s`,so change

```
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s (`sensor_id`, `value`, `unit`, `datetime`)
 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
 (table, data.uuid, data.value, data.unit, data.datetime))
```

To

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO youtable (`sensor_id`, `value`, `unit`, `datetime`) 
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
(data.uuid, data.value, data.unit, data.datetime))
```

Comment: Why can table name not be a parameter? Can you link to the relevant docs?

Comment: @FHTMitchell see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable

Comment: I've changed the table name to a hardcoded one, but the issue still persist. Maybe it is sth up to the variable data.unit, because the error message is ending at exactly that variable. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @ГеоргиНяголов have you tried add `'` to the value?

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter same problem, finally found the root cause is:

*the datetime value should be **string*** -> wrap by quote, like `"datetime_value"` or `'datetime_value'`

so, should your code:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s (`sensor_id`, `value`, `unit`, `datetime`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (table, data.uuid, data.value, data.unit, data.datetime))
```

which datetime value is like `2019-01-02 15:08:59.490163`

should change to:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s (`sensor_id`, `value`, `unit`, `datetime`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, '%s')", (table, data.uuid, data.value, data.unit, data.datetime))
```

which datetime value is like `'2019-01-02 15:08:59.490163'`

and better change to, use backtick for tablename:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO `%s` (`sensor_id`, `value`, `unit`, `datetime`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, '%s')", (table, data.uuid, data.value, data.unit, data.datetime))
```