# How to pass textbox paremeters into sql adapter statements?

Tags: c#, sql

I've a `TextBox` where a user will enter a **table's name** and it'll be passed into the query. The query will pull data from database and display it on the data table.

But I can't seem to do it with `SqlAdapter`, I always get this error like `executescalar`when I can easily add the paremeters and pass it in.

> Incorrect syntax near '@a'.    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect
>   syntax near '@a'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 58:             adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",
>   "%" + Selectdb.Text + "%"); Line 59:             DataTable dt = new
>   DataTable(); Line 60:             adapt.Fill(dt); Line 61:
>   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Line 62:             {

```cs
protected void btn_selectdb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "ready";

    con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    con.Open();
    string a = Convert.ToString(Selectdb.Text);
    string cmdstr = "Select userid,username,email,eventname from @a";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", "%" + Selectdb.Text + "%");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapt.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Not only you are trying to [pass variable as a table name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838490/11683), you are also trying to wrap it into `%`s? What is that supposed to do, select from all tables whose name matches the pattern?

Comment: I think no need to wrap table name in '%'.

Comment: I initially used this, but I don't think this will work with SQLDataAdapter.
I removed the  `%` , still getting syntax error

`md.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Selectdb.Text;`

Comment: The table name and column name in your query has to be static. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable) SO question.

Comment: Warning: If untrusted users use your application, very bad things can happen. Check [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Thank you for this, will be looking more into parameterized queries/sql injection.

Answer (score 2):

You *can't* pass *table name* as a query parameter (diffrent table names mean different query, not same query with different parameter). However, you can try formatting (or string interpolation):

```
    //TODO: validate Selectdb.Text: we don't want SQL injection, e.g.
    // Selectdb.Text = "MyTable; delete from OtherTable"
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(Selectdb.Text, "^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$")) {
      //Something wrong with Selectdb.Text - is it a real table?
    }

    using (con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
      con.Open();

      string cmdstr = 
        $@"select userid,
                  username,
                  email,
                  eventname 
             from [{Selectdb.Text}]"; 

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con)) {
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapt.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
          GridView1.DataSource = dt;
          GridView1.DataBind();
        }
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not wrap table name in %%. Then it has a chance of working.

In any case, I would simply do

```
string cmdstr = "Select userid,username,email,eventname from [" + Selectdb.Text + "]";
```

Comment: A warning about SQL Injection would be wise

Comment: Thank you for this! Solved!