# C# data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

The following code raises an exception `datatype mistmach in criteria expression`. Where does the exception come from ? Generated query works in `Microsoft Access` with no problems.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    if (column.DataType == typeof(String))
    {
        if (column.ColumnName != "ID1" && column.ColumnName != "ID" && column.ColumnName != "Geometry" && column.ColumnName != "Geometry_SK")
        {
            string query = "UPDATE " + tb_tablename.Text.Trim() + " SET " + column.ColumnName + " = Replace([" + column.ColumnName + "], Chr(10), \"\");";

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As example generated SQL code is `UPDATE Necropolis SET NAME_MR = Replace([NAME_MR], Chr(10), "");` . After generating its execute with cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Parameters version shows `Syntax error in query. Incomplete query clause.`.

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
                            {
                                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE @target SET [@columnname] = Replace([@columnname], Chr(10), '');";

                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@target", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = tb_tablename.Text.Trim();
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@columnname", OleDbType.VarChar)).Value = column.ColumnName;

                                MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);

                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
```

Comment: @tymtam And i like there is column ID and ID1 :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `query`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you mistake type stored in database like Varchar and identifiers that should be static and cannot be query parameters. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable

Answer (score 0):

are you sure, that `query` gives a valid SQL statement?
I am not sure, but `=Replace([xyz], Chr(10), \"\");` does not look like a valid SQL statement fo me... 
I think, you should use two seperate strings for the columname:

```
string col_org = column.ColumnName;
string col_new = column.ColumnName.Replace(Chr(10), "\"");
string query = "UPDATE " + tb_tablename.Text.Trim() + " SET " + col_org + " = " + "+ col_new + ";";
```

Can you give us an example of the update string?

Comment: UPDATE Necropolis SET NAME_MR = Replace([NAME_MR], Chr(10), "");

Comment: I would say, that at least `Replace([NAME_MR]` should be `Replace("[NAME_MR]"` but then I cannot help further, because of lacking SQL experience

Comment: If i did thisit becomes string and replace all data - i try it. Tthis is a column name in table.