# How to pass the table name as a parameter in SQL and update the table name

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example:

```
exec SP_ChangeNameOfTable tbl1_data_20200124


SELECT * 
INTO #TEMP_DATA 
FROM [LOADED].DBO.tbl1_data_20200123 
WHERE [Owner] IS NULL
```

I want to change this table name from `20200123` to `20200124` using a stored procedure.

Comment: Dynamic SQL? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Comment: This would NOT be a problem if you did not embed important facts in the name of the table. This path leads to madness. Go back before it's too late. And tsql already has a function to [rename a table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use dynamic sql while trying to pass dynamic table name in SP.

something like,

```
create procedure SP_ChangeNameOfTable
(
  @table_name as varchar(200)
)
As
begin
declare @sc as varchar(max)='SELECT * into #TEMP_DATA FROM
[LOADED].[dbo].'+@table_name+' where [Owner] is null'
execute(@sc);
end
```

Call the SP as you like,

```
exec SP_ChangeNameOfTable 'tbl1_data_20200124'
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b3851e9fc8a0c9608b05fdb2319a378)

Comment: Did you forget the brackets? `exec SP_ChangeNameOfTable 'tbl1_data_20200124'`

Comment: I meant single quotes)

Comment: I would suggest using `QUOTENAME(@table_name)` to add the delimiters, which would also make it safe from SQL Injection