# Delete from variable name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure in which I have a `sourcetable` input parameter and I want to use delete statement to delete rows from a destination table corresponding to that source table value, e.g.:

```sql
Create proc spdeleteRows
    @sourcetable varchar(50)
As
Begin
    Declare @destname varchar(50)
    Select @destname = destname from tblConfig where sourcetable=@sourcetable
    Delete from @destname where convert(date,loaddate) =getdate();
End
```

How do I do it?
It shows error at `@destname` since it is declared as varchar but I cannot declare it as table variable since I will also have to define its structure as well which will be dynamic.
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table name as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use dynamic SQL. I've made a slight assumption on the `WHERE`, but this is likely what you're after:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.spdeleteRows @SourceTable sysname AS --corrected spelling, changed to correct data type.
BEGIN

    DECLARE @DestName sysname = (SELECT destname FROM dbo.tblConfig WHERE sourcetable = @SourceTable);

    --changed WHERE, no column converted to a date will ever equal GETDATE(), as datetime has a high precedence than date.
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'DELETE FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@DestName) + N' WHERE loaddate >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AND loaddate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()));'; 

    --PRINT @SQL;
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you best bet would be [dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/), that way you would be able to build the query to execute as a string. This isn't exactly recommended though as it's easy to make mistakes when you don't have SSMS supporting you, not to mention the stored procedure can fail if anything changes.

Definitely start by checking sys.tables to see if the name actually exists.