# Conditional From Statements in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to something like the following in SQL Server, is this possible?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   if (val == 0) 
     table1
   else 
     table2
)
```

Nothing like this seems to work, how would you accomplish this?

Comment: By `val` do you mean a variable `@val`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/table-name-as-variable

Comment: Hello! Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), knowing how to ask is the key to get an answer around here.

Answer (score 1):

Just `union` your 2 queries together and use the parameter condition in the `where` clause e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE @Val = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE @Val <> 0;
```

Assuming `Val` should be `@Val` (i.e. a variable). The logic doesn't make sense if its a column.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 where @Val = 0)   
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table1
END
ELSE  
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table2
END
```

Comment: While this may be adequate for simple queries, I’m assuming the reason the OP is asking is because they have a more complicated query that they don’t want to repeat. Also, I believe they’ve already established the basis for `@Val`, and so don’t need to introduce a query to validate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add some explanation along with code snippets so other users can understand how the solution was arrived at.