# INSERT INTO @TableName

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert data into a table based on a variable, but SQL Server is not recognising the table in the variable.

```
INSERT INTO @tableNameH
SELECT * FROM @tableName;
```

It this not supported in T-SQL?

Comment: You are trying to insert into a variable, not a table

Comment: but the variable is the table name ^

Comment: You cannot use a variable name as a table name

Comment: It is not a table name. Here is table variable DECLARE @InTable TABLE(ID INT NOT NULL, VAL VARCHAR(100));

Comment: And you selected data to be inserted from the same table?

Comment: Yes as DavidG says, dynamic SQL is the way to go if you want to set the table name at execute time.

Comment: Thank you! I needed the EXEC :)

Comment: @PeterSmith Then, you know, vote to close...

Comment: Careful, the accepted dupe is open to injection. You should be using `QUOTENAME` to properly quote dynamic objects, shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23317992/2029983).