# Update table with auto increment using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to translate this simple sql statement into sp_executesql, because the table name is variable:

```
UPDATE @TableName SET @i = RowNumber = @i + 1
```

This is what I came up with, but it gives an error upon execution : "Must declare the table variable "@TableName".

```
DECLARE @i AS INT ;
SET @i = 0 ;
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLString = N'UPDATE @TableName SET @i = RowNumber = @i + 1';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@TableName VARCHAR(30), @i  TINYINT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @TableName=@TableName, @i = @i;
```

I'm trying to add another column to an existing table, that is basically like an identity column (incremented ID). Tables already have an Id column and I can't drop/update it.

Please don't recommend identity column.

I'm executing this query inside a stored procedure, and @TableName comes in as a parameter and is the name of a temp table, so I was expecting it to be available inside all the inner scopes (including the sp_exec).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is very product specific.)

Comment: Well, it's half a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/a-table-name-as-a-variable), and a failure to declare `@i` as `output`.

Comment: Aside: Lacking a `where` clause the `update` will apply to all rows. If there is more than one row, which `RowNumber` do you expect to get back? You might also want to look at [sequence numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: That isn't how you run a dynamic statement either. You need to safely inject the value with `QUOTENAME`. If you could parametrise a table name like that, you wouldn't need dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Sql Server 2016

Answer (score 2):

First of all, table name cannot be parametrized. I propose to provide it as string literal secured with `QUOTENAME` instead. If both schema and tablename are provided, they have to be provided as separate parameters and both quoted.

Second: `SET @i = RowNumber = @i + 1'` looks a way to iteratively change RowNumber with consecutive integers. For that I would use updatetable cte with `ROW_NUMBER` and add starting position(here @i);

Third: It is assumed that column `RowNumber` already exists in table. If not dynamic `ALTER TABLE <TableName> ADD RowNumber INT` have to be issued first.

Full code:

```
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME = 't';

DECLARE @i AS INT = 0 ;
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @SQLString = 
N'WITH cte AS (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) FROM <TableName>)
  UPDATE cte SET RowNumber = @i + rn';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@i  TINYINT';

SET @SQLString = REPLACE(@SQLString, '<TableName>', QUOTENAME(@TableName));

PRINT @SQLString;  -- debug

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @i = @i;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9a4a5d198b35487b8204317eb2e42383)**

Answer (score 0):

Use **CONCAT** function instead of **+ Operator**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=NULL

DECLARE @TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)='Employee',@Col_NAME NVARCHAR(MAX)='Rw'

SET @SQL=CONCAT('SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as ID FROM ',QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME))

SELECT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)
```

*Update Table Column*

By using **Nested Sub - Query** you can update the Column of the table

```
SET @SQL=CONCAT('UPDATE X',' SET X.',@Col_NAME,' = X.ID FROM (SELECT ',@Col_NAME,', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as ID FROM ',QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME),' ) X')

SELECT @SQL

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates how to handle the various parameters and return a value from the dynamic SQL.

Rather than using a table-per-counter, the code uses a single table of counters with a name (`CounterName`) assigned to each. Incrementing the different counters within the table is shown.

Instead of passing in a value to be incremented, e.g. the OP's `@i`, the counters maintain their own values and the incremented value is returned on each execution. If passing in the value to be incremented is a requirement then the `update` can be easily changed to use the value of `@pCounter` as a source and the value can be passed in and returned using one parameter.

The table name is embedded in the `update` statement and, as such, cannot be passed as a parameter. It must be inserted into the statement while it is being assembled. `QuoteName` is used to handle problem names, e.g. `Space Here`, and offer some protection against SQL injection.

The code can be tested at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4efc73dff7d775d4cfe6a4bb6033754e). (At the time of this writing SQL Server 2019 appears to be non-functional at db<>fiddle. Hence the use of SQL Server 2017.)

```
-- Sample data.
-- The   Counters   table has a row for each counter to be kept, rather than a table per counter.
create table Counters ( CounterId Int Identity, Counter Int Default 0, CounterName NVarChar(64) );
insert into Counters ( CounterName ) values ( 'Shoes' ), ( 'Widgets' );
select * from Counters;

-- Build the query.
declare @Counter as Int = 0;
declare @SQL as NVarChar(500);
declare @ParameterDefinitions as NVarChar(100);
declare @TableName as SysName = N'Counters';
declare @CounterName as NVarChar(64) = 'Widgets';

-- Note that the table name needs to be substituted into the query here, not passed as a parameter.
-- Using different names for the parameters within the query and the variables being passed makes
--   things a little clearer.
set @SQL =
  N'update ' + QuoteName( @TableName ) +
    ' set @pCounter = Counter += 1' +
    ' where CounterName = @pCounterName;';
set @ParameterDefinitions = N'@pCounterName NVarChar(64), @pCounter Int Output';

-- Execute the query.
-- Note that   output   parameters must be specified here as well as in the parameter definitions.
execute sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @ParameterDefinitions,
  @pCounterName = @CounterName, @pCounter = @Counter output;
select @CounterName as [@CounterName], @Counter as [@Counter];
select * from Counters;

execute sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @ParameterDefinitions,
  @pCounterName = @CounterName, @pCounter = @Counter output;
select @CounterName as [@CounterName], @Counter as [@Counter];
select * from Counters;

-- Try a different counter.
set @CounterName = N'Shoes';
execute sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL, @ParameterDefinitions,
  @pCounterName = @CounterName, @pCounter = @Counter output;
select @CounterName as [@CounterName], @Counter as [@Counter];
select * from Counters;

-- Houseclean.
drop table Counters;
```

Answer (score -1):

When you put variables inside quotes it don't been evaluated, just text.
Also it's better to explicit write column name that you want to update.

```
DECLARE @i AS INT ; 
SET @i = 0 ;
DECLARE @ColumnName as NVARCHAR(1000) ='MyColumn'
DECLARE @TableName as NVARCHAR(1000) = 'MyTable'
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500);

SET @SQLString = N'UPDATE ' +  @TableName + ' SET ' + @ColumnName  + ' = ' + @i + '+1';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString;
```

Conclusion - you should concatenate whole update string in single variable and then run it by sp_executesql