# How to select * from variable(Table) in IF statement in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to select from a table that is variable in the IF statement. Here is my question.

```
--ItemProcedure (stored procedure name)
--Item (table name)
Itemcode ItemName    qty
--------------------------
item123  Monitor     100
item456  Laptop      50
item789  Keyboard    10
```

```
Exec ItemProcedure 'Item'
```

```
Declare @Msg as varchar(50)

IF Exists (Select * from @TableName where Itemcode = 'item123')
BEGIN
    SET @Msg = 'Item exists'
END

ELSE

BEGIN
    SET @Msg = 'Item not exists'
END

Select @Msg
```

is there any method that can do this? please advise.

Comment: Is the `SELECT * FROM [table]` just an example? Because having that as a stored procedure adds nothing in terms of expressiveness or security; the client may as well submit that statement itself. This sort of thing requires dynamic SQL, which is never convenient to work with on the database side.

Comment: @jarlh I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: I'm sorry, your question doesn't make sense. What is the actual code you are running and what is the error/problem that you have? To "select * from variabletable in stored procedure", you do exactly what you've written: `Select * from @TableName` are you trying to capture stored procedure output into a table variable? That is a common question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi Jeroen, I've edited my question.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hi Nick, I got 5 projects that using the same method, I do not want to create 5 procedures, I decided to use a variable instead of the actual table name, so this can be done in 1 procedure. and my intention is to assign the table name to ```@TableName``` then I can ```Select * from @TableName```.

Comment: Oh. You can't do that. You'll need to do use dynamic SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/a-table-name-as-a-variable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A table name as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/a-table-name-as-a-variable)

Comment: Keep in mind that SQL is not like normal programming. If you're finding you have lots of duplicate code, there may be some other design issue. As per @JeroenMostert comment, "having that as a stored procedure adds nothing in terms of expressiveness or security"

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks, Nick. it helps to solve the table name as a variable and works fine. ```Declare @TableName, SET @TableName = 'TEST' EXEC('Select * FROM ' + @TableName')``` but I cannot put this into IF statement, for example: ```IF Exists (EXEC('Select * FROM ' + @TableName')```, it appear an error(Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'. Expecting '(', or SELECT ).

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you are trying to do with the `if`. You'll need to provide details if you want assistance

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Hi Nick, I already edited my question, please have a look, thanks.

Comment: How many different `@TableName` are there? Will they all have the same column or different columns? If there are less than, say, ten, you are probably better off just hard coding them all. You can do this with dynamic SQL, but dynamic SQL is to be avoided

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes, they have the same columns. why I want to do this because I want to separate the project don't want to mix up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two tables, ItemsA and ItemsB, you can create a view that combines them:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_ItemsAll
AS
    SELECT ItemCode, ItemName, Qty, 'ItemsA' as TblName FROM ItemsA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ItemCode, ItemName, Qty, 'ItemsB' as TblName FROM ItemsB
GO

SELECT ItemCode, ItemName, Qty
FROM vw_ItemsAll
WHERE TblName = @TableName
```

I've done this and it seems to work pretty well.