# Print selected values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

If there are several tables, I would like to find out the value of col1 when col2 is null from these tables, and print the values through a stored procedure.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| a | A |
| b | null |
| b | B |
| c | C |
| a | null |

Expected ouput:
`a,b`

```
--what I did but can not work

create proc sp_getValue
@tableName varchar(30)
as
declare @result nvarchar(max)
select distinct col1=@result　from @tableName
print @result
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You want `a` and `b` just the way you printed or as a table? Anyway, I suggest you use `exec`.

Comment: I want to print them. I had tried to wirte the select statement as string and exec the string but can not work.

Comment: To find the rows, you need to use `WHERE col2 IS NULL`. However, the construct `from @tableName` is never going to work: the FROM clause does not accept @parameter values, the table name needs to be written explicitly in the query because the compiler checks if the table exists + all columns that you use from it, before any parameter values are evaluated. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838490/1220550) for how to work around that.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for help. I check the post. It helps!

Comment: Having multiple tables with the same schema is normally a design flaw

Comment: Rarely is the use of PRINT in a stored procedure a useful technique to provide information to an application for consumption. It is acceptable for debugging or learning only IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the table name as an argument, you should use `exec`.

```
create proc sp_getValue
 @tableName varchar(30)
as
  exec('select distinct col1 from '+ quotename(@tableName) + ' where col2 is null');
```

To turn this table into a string you can output the result into some temp table, and traverse that using a cursor. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @value  NVARCHAR(30)
DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(100) = '';
CREATE TABLE #temp
(
    col1 NVARCHAR(30)
)

EXEC ('insert into #temp select col1 from ' + @tableName +' where col2 is null')

DECLARE myCur CURSOR FOR SELECT *
                         FROM #temp;
open myCur;
FETCH next from myCur  INTO @value;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @result = @result + @value + ',';
        FETCH next from myCur INTO @value;
    END

PRINT @result

close myCur;
DEALLOCATE myCur;
```

Comment: Thank you. If I want to print the output values,then transfer the values to string, and each value has a comma following, like this:`a,b`, what can I do?

Comment: I suggest running them through a cursor. I'll edit the answer.