# Why this count function throws error "Must declare the scalar variable "@MyColumn"." C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to write a function -like `Dcount` and `Dlookup` in VBA Access- in a public class to use it everywhere in my project so I did the following :

```
  public class MyTools
    {
        SqlConnection Cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     //   DataView dv = new DataView();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader DataRead;

        // Variables
        string MyColumn, MyTable, MyCondition,DlookResult;
        int DcountResult;

        // Methods & Functions
        // Dcount
        public int DCount(string MyColumn, string MyTable, string MyCondition)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(@MyColumn) from @MyTable where @MyColumn = @MyCondition", Cn);
            da.Fill(dt);
            DcountResult = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0].ToString());
            return DcountResult;
        }
    }

    // Dlookup


}
```

And tried to use it like this :

```
  int Result = DCount(txtColumn.Text, txtTable.Text, txtCond.Text);
            txtResult.Text = null;
            txtResult.Text = Result.ToString();
```

But it throws the error  "Must declare the scalar variable "@MyColumn".
I tried to use `sqlcommand` and `DataRead` but I need to close the connection after the `return` and it became `Unreachable` or close before the `return` so it returns nothing , That's why i used `SqlDataAdapter`.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: You can't substitute in the table and column names that way... only literal values. Additionally, it's a mistake to keep an actual connection object for the lifetime of a class like this; it interferes with ADO.Net's own connection pooling and makes things slower and use more memory. Instead, only keep a local copy of the connection string. The rest of the variables should all be scoped to the method.

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter` has nothing to do with the ability to close the connection; if the respective code was marked as unreachable, you did something wrong. You are not providing any variables at all to the SQL command, which the error message is telling you about. Even if you were [providing parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/542510/11683) to the SQL command correctly, you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2838490/11683) parametrize `@MyTable` or `@MyColumn`.

Comment: Thanks for reply  , What is the best way to do what I need ? I need a function which counts a variable value from variable column from variable table , So I can use it everywhere without keep typing SQL queries ?

Comment: Side note: while I like trolling (and even better self-trolling) I'd recommend not to use the same names for fields/properties and method parameters.

Comment: Look into dynamic sql if you need that flexibility.

Comment: Looks like regular LINQ-to-SQL should be much better `myRepo.GetCars().Where(x=> x.Color=="green").Count()`...

Comment: That SQL statement has some errors. 1- Your `from @MyTable` would not work as intended, because SQL Server does not allow passing table names as parameters. 2- In a similar fashion, but different, the `@MyColumn` would not be replaced by your column name, you would get something similat to `where 'name' = 'Josh'` and that is not what you want. 3- You never pass to the SqlCommand inside the SqlAdapter any parameters.

Comment: Also you need to dispose the connection, command, reader and adapter with `using`, do *not* cache them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have to look something more like this:

```
public class MyTools
{
    private static string ConnectionString {get;} = @"Server = AMR-PC\SQLEXPRESS ; Database=PlanningDB ; Integrated Security = True";

    public static int DCount(string MyTable, string MyColumn, string MyCondition)
    {
        string sql = $"Select Count({MyColumn}) from {MyTable} where {MyColumn} = @MyCondition";

        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyCondition", MyCondition);
            cn.Open();
            return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Just be aware this uses dynamic SQL, and is **more than a little dangerous**. In fact, *you should not do this*. I know you don't want to "keep typing SQL queries", but that might be exactly what you should do.

Comment: I'm surprised to see you recommending this, at least you do notate in bold it's dangerous :)

Comment: Thanks so much , Why it is dangerous ? Sql Injection ?

Comment: @CsharpNewbie yes...

Comment: It is not that important to be hacked :)

Comment: It kind of is...

Comment: @CsharpNewbie At least what Joel is saying is best practice, you shouldn't be doing queries this way anyways. Get in the habit of changing things now and not later...

Comment: 20 minutes ago I got a phone call from a relative that got malware in their phone and got their bank account hacked. Do never downplay security

Comment: Thanks for warning me , Is there a safer way to get it done ?

Comment: querying the database schema checking if the table name and column name are valid ones would get rid of the sql injection vulknerability (remember to escape the column names with `[]`)