# Defining SQL Server table name from date

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Server database has tables named after the load date in this format

```
## FROM [GL_202206].[dbo].[GL_ACCOUNT_20220602].
```

I have done a query that can generate a similar sting as the table name as below:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('[GL_', YEAR(GETDATE()), FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'MM'),
           '].[dbo].[GL_ACCOUNT_', CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), ']')
```

How can I get the string to make the table name in the query?

Say

```
SELECT 
    ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNAME 
FROM 
    [GL_202206].[dbo].[GL_ACCOUNT_20220602]
```

Comment: I think this is only possible with dynamic sql

Comment: But honestly, when you need table names like that is smells like a bad design to me

Comment: I know you might not have any say here, but this is an awful way to define these tables. There should be **ONE TABLE**, with these date values in a column as the first part of a composite primary key.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838490/a-table-name-as-a-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL is correct, you only need to execute it.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = null;
SELECT @sql = 'select ACCOUNTID, ACCOUNTNAME from ' +
    CONCAT('[GL_', YEAR(GETDATE()), FORMAT (GETDATE(), 'MM'),
           '].[dbo].[GL_ACCOUNT_', CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112), ']');
exec (@sql)
```